# Included script works no fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I have velocity file and  these part of code inside it

```
<input type="radio" name="activity" class ='message' id="#springUrl('/resources/ajax/notify/test.html')">
```

I have added `notifications.js` file. So inside these `notifications.js` file code `alert();`  or

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert();
});
```

works good , but  I CAN'T perform code

```
$(".message").click(function(){
            alert("message");
        });
```

How can i access   `".message"`  class  inside `notifications.js` file?

I've included notifications.js

```
<script src="#springUrl('/resources/js/notifications.js')"></script>
```

Comment: Is `message` button click handler inside _window load_ or _document-ready handler_?

Comment: You may want to look at an event-delegation approach using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (with something like `$("body").on("click", ".message", function() {...})`)

Comment: thanks , your solution helped me